# Stop suggesting Microsoft Edge browser in start menu when typing "internet"

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer, start-menu

I use Chrome as my primary browser but *must* use Internet Explorer to be able to remote in to my work via Remote Desktop web client (since it uses ActiveX plugins).

To start an app, I would often type out the name from the start menu unless I had a pinned link or shortcut handy. But if I type "internet" as if I were trying to start Internet Explorer, I will always be recommended Edge and have it highlighted by default.

[image: typing internet recommends edge]

I will never be able to use Edge here so stop recommending it... **can this behavior be disabled somehow?**

Not even pinning the Internet Explorer link to the start menu prevents this. If I had any other shortcuts that started with the word "internet," it still offers Edge and is preselected. At least if I type in "chrome," Chrome is selected first.

Windows 10 Pro 1909 (18363.900)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either disabled it through a group policy[.](https://winaero.com/blog/remove-microsoft-edge-suggestions-from-the-start-menu/)

By creating the key, `DisableSearchBoxSuggestions`, with a value of 1[.](https://betanews.com/2020/06/08/windows-10-start-menu-edge-ads/)  At the following location:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer
```

Based on my research that might only work if you are running `Windows 10 version 2004`.

If that does not work, verify you have disabled, `Occasionally show suggestions in Start`

[image]

If that still does not work: [Here](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/159097-remove-edge-start-menu-recommendation.html) has a registry file that indicates will disable the suggestion.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search]
"CortanaConsent"=dword:00000000
"AllowSearchToUseLocation"=dword:00000000
"BingSearchEnabled"=dword:00000000
```

[DisableWebSearch](https://pastebin.com/QwzUg5Xv)

Comment: The reg file in the linked page is locked behind a login. But the file just sets values in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search` key: `CortanaConsent=0`, `AllowSearchToUseLocation=0`, `BingSearchEnabled=0`

Comment: Ah, it does work (the 1909 registry changes). Just needed to restart Windows Explorer to pick up the settings. :)