# How to remove "Restore microsoft recommended settings. Set edge as the default browser"

Tags: windows-10

I recently noticed Windows 10 flash a "recommendation" message when I click "Type here to search"

[image]

When I click X it goes away. But whenever I restart my computer it comes back. How can I permanently remove it. Microsoft are pushing their luck here.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to remove the Microsoft Edge recommendation message in the Start menu by looking at [this answer on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1565338/stop-suggesting-microsoft-edge-browser-in-start-menu-when-typing-internet) and [this article](https://www.bennetrichter.de/en/tutorials/windows-10-disable-web-search/).

First, I searched for "Start settings" in the Windows 10 Settings app and turned off "Occasionally show suggestions in Start".

Then, I opened regedit and navigated to

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows
```

Since my Windows key didn't have an `Explorer` key under it, I created one within the Windows key, then within the Explorer key I created a DWORD Value called `DisableSearchBoxSuggestions` and set it to `1`.

[Image of DWORD in regedit in the Explorer key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACNZX.png)

For good measure, I also disabled Cortana and Internet Searches in Start as suggested by the answer, although I'm not sure if that's strictly necessary for this to work. Since I'm on Windows 10 Pro, I started gpedit and navigated to `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Search` and then changed the policies [in this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR71Z.png) I imagine you could do the same with the suggested registry values in the linked answer.

Finally, I restarted my computer, and after a minute or so (and opening up the same "Start settings" again), the Recommended Edge notification disappeared and now my Start menu Search [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnUhX.png).

Answer (score 1):

Hum... Do you meet the similar notification in Setting?
"Get even more out Windows"
Enter it, skip the set recommended setting for Edge, complete the rest, and the annoyance disappears!
I have done it since 21H1 update, and no more annoyance banners about Edge.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).